# Credential Validation from database in Oracle JET

Tags: rest, validation, authentication, oracle-jet

I have created a sample application in `Oracle JET` which would route to the homepage upon login.

I want to validate the user credentials(username and password) with the table in the database using `RESTful` web services and only upon successful validation I want the application to be routed to the homepage.

Since I am new to `Oracle JET` and have less knowledge about integrating and validating user input with the data in the database, it would be a great if someone could help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax method to call restful web services.

Here is an sample that can help you.

```
 self.username = ko.observable("");
 self.password = ko.observable("");
 self.login = function(data, event)
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://restservicesforlogin?username="+self.username()+"&userpwd="+self.password()+"",
      type: 'GET',
      headers: {
        your headers Details
                },

   success: function(data)
   {  


 if(self.ERROR_CODE()=='S')
 {

      oj.Router.rootInstance.go('homePage'); 
 }  
 if(self.ERROR_CODE()=='E')
 {
     alert("Invalid username/password");
     self.isLoggedIn(false);

 }  
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception)
        {
           alert("Internal Server Error") ; 
         }
   })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it worked well. It would be great if you explain about the **self.ERROR_CODE()=='S'** and **self.ERROR_CODE()=='E'** as in how the error code function works. Thank you.

Comment: those are variables .my rest services return error code based on the input credentials.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me to validate user credentials in the login page.